# How to create a new column using looping and rbind in r?

Tags: r, loops

I have a data similar like this. I would like to make 3 columns (date1, date2, date3) by using looping and rbind. It is because I am requied to do it by only that method. 
(all I was told is making a loop,  subset the data, sort it make a new data frame then rbind it to make a new column.)

```
    year  month day  id
    2011    1   5   3101
    2011    1   14  3101
    2011    2   3   3101
    2011    2   4   3101
    2012    1   27  3153
    2012    2   20  3153
    2012    2   22  3153
    2012    3   1   3153
    2013    1   31  3103
    2013    2   1   3103
    2013    2   4   3103
    2013    3   4   3103
    2013    3   6   3103
```

The result I expect is:

date1: number of days from 2011, January 1st, start again from 1 in a new year.

date2: number of days of an id working in a year, start again from 1 in a new year.

date3: number of days open within a year, start again from 1 in a new year.

(all of the dates are in ascending order)

```
    year month day  id  date1 date2 date3
    2011    1   5   3101    5   1   1
    2011    1   14  3101    14  2   2
    2011    2   3   3101    34  3   3
    2011    2   4   3101    35  4   4
    2012    1   27  3153    27  1   1
    2012    2   20  3153    51  2   2
    2012    2   22  3153    53  3   3
    2012    3   1   3153    60  4   4
    2013    1   31  3103    31  1   1
    2013    2   1   3103    32  2   2
    2013    2   4   3103    35  3   3
    2013    3   4   3103    94  4   4
    2013    3   6   3103    96  5   5
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Hi. What have you tried to do so far? SO is not a homework solution platform.

Comment: I tried some code but it goes to nowhere. so which platform it belongs to?

Comment: you can do it easily without using a for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using unnecessary for loop and subset, here is the answer below

```
df <- read.table(text =" year  month day  id
    2011    1   5   3101
    2011    1   14  3101
    2011    2   3   3101
    2011    2   4   3101
    2012    1   27  3153
    2012    2   20  3153
    2012    2   22  3153
    2012    3   1   3153
    2013    1   31  3103
    2013    2   1   3103
    2013    2   4   3103
    2013    3   4   3103
    2013    3   6   3103",header = T)

library(lubridate)
df$date1 <- yday(mdy(paste0(df$month,"-",df$day,"-",df$year)))
df$date2 <- ave(df$year, df$id, FUN = seq_along)

df$date3 <- ave(df$year, df$year, FUN = seq_along)
```

Comment: I have checked. the date2 result has the number of days over 365 and date3 has the number of days over 10000, it's not supposed to be true because there are just 365 days in a year.

Comment: in my output there is no value greater than 10 , how did you get 10000 .did you use other data?